# Custom NSView with rounded corners and drop shadow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsbezierpath, nsshadow

I'm trying to create a custom NSView with both rounded corners and a drop shadow. I created an NSView subclass and have the following drawRect: method

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect([self bounds].origin.x + 3, [self bounds].origin.y + 3, [self bounds].size.width - 6, [self bounds].size.height - 6);

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect xRadius:5.0 yRadius:5.0];
    [path addClip];

    NSShadow *shadow = [[[NSShadow alloc] init] autorelease];
    [shadow setShadowColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius:2.0f];
    [shadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0.f, -1.f)];
    [shadow set];

    [[NSColor controlColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

The result is an NSView drawn with rounded corners, but no shadow (but I do see tinges of the red color around corners in the anti-aliasing).  If I comment out the NSBezierPath then I will get a square NSView with a shadow.  I didn't see anything in the docs to suggest that NSShadow and NSBezierPath are mutually exclusive, so I'm obviously missing something.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the shadow doesn't respect the clipping path. Did you try `[path fill]` instead of `NSFillRect`?

Comment: I put in [path fill] in the place of NSFillRect() and the result was the same

Comment: Just in case anyone read this [path fill] worked for my to draw a rounded corner rect inside drawRect

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CALayer's `cornerRadius` method to get the rounded corner effect.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I'm using CALayer correctly, but I added the following to my initWithFrame: 
`[self setWantsLayer:YES];`
`[self setLayer:[CALayer layer]];`        
`self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;`  That doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Can you try it again but place `[self setWantsLayer:YES];` after the other two lines.

Comment: Tried swapping the lines -- still the same outcome